# How to create curved surface like this

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to make curved surfaces like this structure?

Answer (score 2):

I made a short timelapse of how you can achieve this. Basically I started with a cube, scaled it, added loops, twisted it and gave it the right shape. Then I bended the mesh on the Z axis at 60°. Finally I arrayed it with an empty  and cleaned the whole thing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQr2w.jpg

Comment: quite a simple approach!

Comment: nice, you should show some screenshots of the steps

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a complete answer, as this is a rather difficult thing imo.
Without sculpting: start with the triangle surface at the bottom side there, deform it as it is and build off of that. You can make this tri-cross shape first to lean on it for reference. My first idea on how to do that would be by creating a cylinder with 6 verts, with the knife tool half every second outside face on the Z axis and move those new edges in and bevel them.

Or

Try to create this base mesh that I mentioned above and sculpt those curves in with the flattening brush.